# Using ndarray.flatten() python for array of several arrays, Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have to following set of indices

```
ind = array([[array([0, 1, 3, 4])],
            [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])],
            [array([1, 2, 4, 5])],
            [array([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7])],
            [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])],
            [array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8])],
            [array([3, 4, 6, 7])],
            [array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])],
            [array([4, 5, 7, 8])]], dtype=object)
```

of some data let say X;

```
X = array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
           [ 0.5,  0. ],
           [ 1. ,  0. ],
           [ 0. ,  0.5],
           [ 0.5,  0.5],
           [ 1. ,  0.5],
           [ 0. ,  1. ],
           [ 0.5,  1. ],
           [ 1. ,  1. ]])
```

Is there a way I can replace the following **forloop** with some built in function in python;

```
A_flat = ind.flatten()    
for i in range(N):
     print X[i,0] - X[A_flat[i],0]

> [ 0.  -0.5  0.  -0.5]
  [ 0.5  0.  -0.5  0.5  0.  -0.5]
  [ 0.5  0.   0.5  0. ]
  [ 0.  -0.5  0.  -0.5  0.  -0.5]
  [ 0.5  0.  -0.5  0.5  0.  -0.5  0.5  0.  -0.5]
  [ 0.5  0.   0.5  0.   0.5  0. ]
  [ 0.  -0.5  0.  -0.5]
  [ 0.5  0.  -0.5  0.5  0.  -0.5]
  [ 0.5  0.   0.5  0. ]
```

and store the result to a 9 by 9 zero matrix (or sparse matrix) to obtain let say B with **correct indices**;

Comment: What is `N` supposed to be?

Comment: @chrisaycock

   `N = len(X[:,0])`, here `N` is `9`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the problem is described, the answer is no.

If `ind` had a homogenous number of columns, then the answer would be yes.

Try

```
import numpy as np
ind = np.array([[4, 5, 6],
                [0, 1, 2]])

print X[np.arange(len(ind))[:, np.newaxis], 0] - X[ind, 0]
```

And see if you can reformulate your problem in any way that makes the `ind` array homogeneous in lines and columns. If this is impossible, then looping in some sense will be unavoidable.

In case there is a fixed upper bound on columns, you could try using masked arrays. Let us assume you would like to index `[[4, 5, 6], [0, 1]]`. Then you could write this as

```
mask = np.array([[False, False, False],
                 [False, False, True]])

ind2 = np.ma.masked_where(mask, ind)  # these are the indices that we would be interested in (we do not make use of this line later on)

raw_output = X[np.arange(len(ind))[:, np.newaxis], 0] - X[ind, 0]
masked_output = np.ma.masked_where(mask, raw_output)

print masked_output
```

In order to turn this into the data structure you indicate, you could then continue with the (probably suboptimal and slower) list comprehension

```
list_output = masked_output.tolist()
final_output = [[num for num in arr if num is not None] for arr in list_output]
```

Comment: The number of columns is unknown but the maximum number that each column can have is N. The number of rows is always N. Thats why I ask if there is a way we could store `ind` into a `N` by `N` matrix then call it. Is it possible? Thanks for your help.